# getting error 500 for place order

Tags: magento2.3.2, http-error-500, place-order

I have a few customers who are getting 500 errors while placing orders. But else other customers not getting any issue, they are doing checkout without any issue. When 500 status comes I have checked parameters.

> cartId":"4047","billingAddress":{"customerAddressId":"58","countryId":"ZA","regionCode":"Gauteng","region":"Gauteng","customerId":"3524","street":["33
>   Ballyclare Drive","Ballywoods Office Park","Cedarwood
>   House"],"company":null,"telephone":"+27823716342","fax":null,"postcode":"2191","city":"Johannesburg","firstname":"iHouzit","lastname":"Team","middlename":null,"prefix":null,"suffix":null,"customAttributes":[],"saveInAddressBook":null},"paymentMethod":{"method":"payfast","po_number":null,"additional_data":null,"extension_attributes":{"agreement_ids":["1"]

above all parameters have that customer. Then why it giving 500. Please let me know the solution.

Comment: check you var/exception.log and var/system.log and update your question with error log.

Comment: Invalid customer address id 58 at /var/www/html/ihouzit/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteAddressValidator.php:79)"}

Comment: UPDATE quote SET customer_is_guest = 0 WHERE customer_id != 0 AND customer_is_guest = 1.. once i tried this solution.but only for few time it works,later same issue I face.I am not getting where to code exact to fix.